# How to use alias in INSERT query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, insert, alias

I have following statement:

```
INSERT INTO room (room_class_id, beds_amount)
    VALUES 
    ((SELECT id FROM room_class WHERE class_name='STANDARD'), 2),
    ((SELECT id FROM room_class WHERE class_name='STANDARD'), 2),
    ((SELECT id FROM room_class WHERE class_name='STANDARD'), 3),
    ((SELECT id FROM room_class WHERE class_name='STANDARD'), 1),
    ...
    and 30+ rows looking like that
```

How can I use alias for room class id to avoid selecting it every time?
When I try

```
INSERT INTO room (room_class_id, beds_amount)
    VALUES 
    ((SELECT id AS st_id FROM room_class WHERE class_name='STANDARD'), 2),
    (st_id, 2),
    (st_id, 3),
    (st_id, 1),
```

I get

ERROR:  column "st_id" does not exist

I'm using PostgreSql 9.6.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want:

```
INSERT INTO room (room_class_id, beds_amount)
    SELECT rc.id, v.beds_amount
    FROM (VALUES ('Standard', 2),
                 ('Standard', 2),
                 ('Standard', 3),
                 ('Standard', 1),
                 ('Luxe', 2)
         ) v(class_name, beds_amount) JOIN
         room_class rc             
         USING (class_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a cross join of the query to the values of the 2nd column like this:

```
INSERT INTO room(room_class_id, beds_amount)
SELECT rc.id, v.beds_amount
FROM (SELECT id FROM room_class WHERE class_name='STANDARD') rc
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (2), (2), (3), (1)) v (beds_amount);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wstJWQ9DVTATAQDWFob4Rx/2).

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wstJWQ9DVTATAQDWFob4Rx/3

Answer (score 0):

Edit: updated answer with additional information provided by OP in a comment.

You can use `WITH` (example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/43b73/1/0):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id AS st_id, ARRAY[2,2,3,1] AS arr 
  FROM room_class 
  WHERE class_name='STANDARD'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id AS st_id, ARRAY[1,2,3,4] AS arr 
  FROM room_class 
  WHERE class_name='LUXE'  
)
INSERT INTO room (room_class_id, beds_amount) 
    SELECT st_id, UNNEST(arr) FROM cte;
```